# device orientation differs from iphone 4 to 5?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, device-orientation

I've written an application and one of it's use cases react to device orientation. On my iPhone 5 everything works fine, but on my testers iPhone 4 nothing happens.

I'm working with test flight checkpoints to see that they are not reaching the flip method, which means that `([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])` either returns different values in different iPhone versions, or I need to check with something else to see if the device is in landscape mode.

```
-(BOOL)checkDeviceOrientation
{
    BOOL orientationError = NO;
    switch ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])
    {
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:     
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:    
            [self setRotationMessage:[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]];
            orientationError = YES;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return orientationError;
}
```

Has anyone encountered the same problem, and any suggestions?

Comment: Where are you checking the orientation?  And are both devices running the same version of iOS?

Comment: @nhgrif both devices run the same ios version and i check the orientation inside a method that is being called on a button click

Comment: relevant code please.

Comment: @Lance there isn't anything special, a switch case on the ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]) in landscape right and left i have a alert.

Comment: Is this inside a particular view controller or app level?

Comment: which version of iOS are the devices running?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it's better to check the status bar orientation rather than the device orientation. The device orientation is the orientation of the physical device, not the UI.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation
```

As an aside, you could be running into the case where the device is `UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp` or `UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown`

Comment: Lance i need the orientation of the physical device, the actual way the user holds the phone. the problem i'm facing is that in iphone 5 i get the correct values whereas in iphone 4 i alway get portrait orientation.

Comment: oh gotcha. yea that makes no sense. Are you sure it's all iPhone 4's or is there a problem with that particular phone? Any chance the accelerometer is broken/disabled (rotation lock maybe?)